# Rails 3 validates numericality throws argument error when blank/nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, validation

This seems like kind of a no-brainer but I want to require a number and make sure it is not greater or less than a predetermined amount:

```
validates :age_min, presence: true, numericality: {
  greater_than: 0, less_than_or_equal_to: :age_max
}
```

This test works as expected

```
test 'user should not be valid with age min greater than age max' do
  user = FactoryGirl.build(:user, age_min: 30, age_max: 20)
  assert !user.valid?
end
```

However, when I try and test that `age_min` is required:

```
test 'user should not be valid without age_min' do
  user = FactoryGirl.build(:user, age_min: nil, age_max: 20)
  assert !user.valid?
end
```

I get `ArgumentError: comparison of Float with nil failed`

It seems strange that Rails doesn't take the nil value into account, or am I missing something? It seems you should be able to get this to work without writing a custom validator, but perhaps I am mistaken.

Comment: Both of your validations are being run.  The "presence: true" validation does not stop the numerically validation from running.  I think you need a :unless => Proc type condition on the numericality validation, but I don't know the syntax off hand.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since your numericality validation for age_min id dependent on the value for age_max, and not a fixed value, I think you want to split your validation out and guard against nil values with procs

```
validates :age_min, :age_max, :presence => true
validates :age_min, :numericality => {greater_than: 0, less_than_or_equal_to: :age_max}, :unless => Proc.new {|user| user.age_min.nil? || user.age_max.nil? }
```

Comment: Well that looks like the cleanest way so far. Thanks!